# Dressing and undressing in a bedroom

Tags: halacha

Would a today's bedroom have a status of the bathroom that Rav Moshe (Igros Moshe YD3 bottom of page [282](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=285&hilite=) - 283. Even though it is not a Halachic requirement per se, there are still actual gedarim for a midas chassidus) permitted one to change in without keeping himself covered (He didn't even permit a bathroom that doesn't have a shower/bath because it is not set aside for nakedness. I was just wondering if nowadays we would consider a bedroom equal to a shower room)?

Meaning: Since a bedroom is set aside for changing maybe it should have a similar permissive status as the bathroom. Since a bedroom is set aside for changing a shirt, pants, skirt, blouse etc maybe it should be permitted to change in a bedroom - at least if the person will NOT remove his/her undergarments which a bedroom is not set aside for.

Comment: This has to do with piety it should not be confused with halakha which has specific parameters.

Comment: Note that reb Moshe want dealing with some mystical characteristics of bathrooms. Rather, iirc he was noting that it is not immodest to chance in a place designed for that. If so, why would a bedroom be different?

Comment: Rav Moshe was specifying a room with a shower/bath because it is a room that is meant to be used for undressing in order to bathe. I was just wondering if the bedrooms nowadays, which are more private areas than they were many years ago and are generally used for dressing and undressing,  would have the same leniency as a bathroom.

Comment: This seems to be the logical application of what he wrote.What sort of proof are you looking for in your answer?

Comment: Rav Moshe specified a room that has a shower or bath because it is a room that is set aside for nakedness. Although it is a stretch, I was wondering if anyone has applied that logic to a bedroom. Rav Moshe surely did not so I'm not sure how it is a logical application of what he wrote. A more logical application would be to say that this leniency does not apply to a bedroom.

Comment: In your question you assume that bedrooms today are set aside for undressing. That being the case, why do you think that Reb Moshe's leniency would not apply? Do you assume that people don't usually fully undress in a bedroom? If so, consider editing that in. I think you would have some difficulty finding a rigorous definition of a pious practice that is not rigorously defined.

Comment: Rav Moshe wrote that it specifically applies to a room that has a bath or shower because it is a room that is set aside for nakedness. He didn't even permit a bathroom that doesn't have a shower/bath because it is not set aside for nakedness. I was just wondering if nowadays we would consider a bedroom equal to a shower room. Igros Moshe YD3 bottom of page 282 - 283. Even though it is not a Halachic requirement per se, there are still actual gedarim for a midas chassidus. Please edit the question to make it more presentable.

Comment: I don't think bedrooms are set aside specifically for being naked in like a bathroom or a shower room would be

Comment: True. But maybe they're set aside for being partially undressed (underwear only) which would permit one to change his shirt/pants in a bedroom, something which is forbidden (middas chassidus) in a different room (even with nobody around)

Comment: Why are we assuming the bedroom Rav Moshe himself had in his apt in NYC when he wrote his teshuvah (1970's I guess) is any different that than the one you and I have in 2016?

Comment: Are you saying that the bedroom of a married couple is not a place set aside for nakedness, at least some of the time?